# How to invoke PS script in Administrator mode remotely

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell

I am setting up an infrastructure in AWS where windows based EC2 instance is being launched through Cloudformation template and a UserData script (Powershell script) is being invoked in the launch configuration of the EC2 instance.
This is how the CF template for the EC2 instance looks like:

```
"<powershell>\n",
"Start-Transcript -Path \"C:\\UserDataTranscript.txt\" -Append",
"Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force",
"Import-Module AWSPowerShell",
{"Fn::Sub": "Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region ${AWS::Region}"},
"New-Item -Path C:\\UserData -ItemType \"directory\" -Force",
{ "Fn::Sub": ["Read-S3Object -BucketName ${UserDataBucket} -Key EC2UserData.ps1 -File C:\\UserData\\EC2UserData.ps1",
    { "UserDataBucket": { "Fn::Select": [0, {"Ref": "S3UserDataFilesParameterStoreKey"}] } }
]},
"C:\\UserData\\EC2UserData.ps1",
"Stop-Transcript",
"</powershell>"
```

And this is how `EC2UserData.ps1` script looks like:

```
$params = @(
        "/q"
        "ADDRESS=$wazuhServerIP"
        "AUTHD_SERVER=$wazuhAuthServerIP"
        "PROTOCOL=`"TCP`""
        "AUTHD_PORT=`"55000`""
    )
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\UserData\wazuh-agent.msi" -ArgumentList $params -PassThru
$proc | Wait-Process -Timeout 40 -ErrorAction Stop
```

I am installing Wazuh agent in the script here which needs Administrator rights to install. I tried adding `-Verb runAs` but no luck.

Comment: What error do you get with `Start-Process ...  -Verb RunAs` ?

Comment: There is no error thrown, thats the weird part to it. I suspect that it could be because UAC pop up to confirm the installation is blocking the installation process. I tried disabling it by running this command but even this fails with access denied error: `Set-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin -Value 0`

Answer (score 1):

After try your template inside CloudFormation I could see some mistakes on that template (the script works well), take a look to this template (based on yours):

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "YOUR_DESIGNER_ID": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 600,
                    "y": 200
                },
                "z": 0,
                "embeds": []
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "WindowsInstance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": "YOUR_KEY_NAME",
                "IamInstanceProfile": "YOUR_INSTANCE_PROFILE",
                "SecurityGroupIds": [ "YOUR_SECURITY_GROUP" ],
                "ImageId": "YOUR_AMI_ID",
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64" : { 
                        "Fn::Join" : [ "",[
                            "<powershell>\n",
                            "Start-Transcript -Path 'C:\\UserDataTranscript.txt' -Append\n",
                            "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force\n",
                            "Import-Module AWSPowerShell\n",
                            { "Fn::Sub": "Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region ${AWS::Region}\n" },
                            "New-Item -Path C:\\UserData -ItemType 'directory' -Force\n",
                            { "Fn::Sub": "Read-S3Object -BucketName USE_VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT -Key EC2UserData.ps1 -File C:\\UserData\\EC2UserData.ps1\n" },
                            { "Fn::Sub": "Read-S3Object -BucketName USE_VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT -Key wazuh-agent.msi -File C:\\UserData\\wazuh-agent.msi\n" },
                            "C:\\UserData\\EC2UserData.ps1\n",
                            "Stop-Transcript\n",
                            "</powershell>"
                        ]]
                    }
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "YOUR_DESIGNER_ID"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added two things here, the `\n` at the end of each statement that I see on AWS examples and I think that you are using too (Fn::Join requires that), and the download of AWS package from S3 bucket. Maybe you have other way to download the MSI but I have tried this and worked like a charm.